# Can't executeUpdate() in Grails/Groovy web application

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to make a CRUD web service with a psql. I achieved this while i had a domain. But now i don't need the domain class and i started to remake this. I can create and delete data from the database but when it comes to edit i get this error:

```
URI
    /Test/customer/edit/2
Class
    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException
Message
    Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'long'. Try 'java.lang.Long' instead
```

I have this controller

```
package test

class CustomerController {
    def customerService

    def index = {
        redirect action: "list"
    }
    def create() {}

    def edit () {
    [customer: customerService.updateAction(params.id,params.name,params.thl,params.dt1)]
}
    def list() {
        [customers : customerService.listAction()]
    }

    def save() {
        println params
        [customer: customerService.insertAction(params.id,params.name,params.thl,params.dt1)]
        redirect action: "list"
    }
    def update(){
    [customer: customerService.updateAction(params.id,params.name,params.thl,params.dt1)]
    redirect action: "list"
}

    def delete(){
        [customer: customerService.deleteAction(params.id)]
        redirect action: "list"
    }
}
```

Web Service

```
package test

import groovy.sql.Sql
import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional
class CustomerService {

    def DataSource

    def listAction(){
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        return sql.rows ("SELECT * FROM  mn")
    }

    def insertAction(String id, String name,String thl,String dt1){
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        sql.execute("INSERT INTO  mn (id, name, thl, dt1) VALUES (${id as long},$name,${thl as long},$dt1)")
    }

    ddef updateAction (String id,String name,String thl,String dt1){
    def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    sql.executeUpdate("UPDATE mn SET  id=${id as long}, name=$name, thl=${thl as long}, dt1=$dt1 where id=${id as long}")
}
    def deleteAction(String id){
        def sql= new Sql(dataSource)
        sql.execute("delete from mn where id=${id as long}")
    }
}
```

and this gsp

```
 <body>
<g:render template="/customer/Header"/>
<g:render template="/customer/Navbar"/>
<h1>Edit contact</h1>
<g:form controller="customer" action="update" method="post">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg 2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id">Id</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" id="id" placeholder="Id">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg 2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg 2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="thl">thlefvno</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="thl" name="thl" placeholder="thlefvno">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class='col-lg 6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for ="dt1">Date :</label>
                    <div class='input-group date' id="dt1">
                        <input id="dt1" name="dt1" type='text' class="form-control">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('#dt1').datetimepicker({
                });
            </script>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class='col-lg 6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6'>
                <g:actionSubmit value="update" class="btn btn-info" role="button" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</g:form>
</body>
</html>
```

SOLUTION:

Service

```
def getCustomerById (Long id) {
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        sql.execute("update mn set  id=$id WHERE id=${id as long}")
    }
```

Controller

```
def edit () {
        [customer: customerService.getCustomerById(params.id as long)]
}
```

Comment: Your UpdateAction method takes id as long, but you sent it as string. try to cast it before passing: 
*customerService.updateAction(params.id as Long,params.name,params.thl,params.dt1)*

Comment: i changed the update action and now i get this:  
URI
    /Test/customer/update
Class
    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException
Message
    Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'long'. Try 'java.lang.Long' instead

Comment: You don't submit id, add the name attribute to your input:
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" placeholder="Id">

Comment: Although _sql.execute("update mn set  id=$id WHERE id=${id as long}")_ works, this is not good solution, because you do unnecessary update. It would be better if you investigate how to get record by id without updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `/Test/customer/edit/2` `edit` action from `CustomerController` is called. There is no *name, thl* and *dt1* in *params* object, because you didn't provide them in the url. There is only *id* which is **2**.
Now you are trying to call `customerService.updateAction` with the following arguments: `customerService.updateAction(2,null,null,null)`
In `updateAction` you convert *thl* like this: `${thl as long}`, but *tgl* is *null* and can't be casted to *long*, because *long* is primitive type and can't be null. You can cast it to *Long* (this is an object, objects can be null) but I don't think it is good solution in this case.
First of all, you should remove casting logic from updateAction. If you need long instead of String - cast it in controller and then pass to the method.
The second observation: do you really need to execute update in edit action? I guess you just need to get your customer by id there and pass it to the gsp:

```
def edit () {
[customer: customerService.getCustomerById(id as String)]
}
```

In this case you should create `getCustomerById` method